# Double bracket in subfigures using subcaption package

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, subcaption

I am using the package \subcaption; I would like my subfigures to be labeled by letters, e.g. (a), and when referencing a subfigure with \ref I would like to get something like Fig. 1(a).
By default, subfigures are indeed labelled by (a) but \ref produces e.g. 1a. 
Following the manual by Axel Sommerfeldt, I tried including the line

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

With this, \ref returns the output that I would like e.g. 1(a), but subfigures are now labelled by double brackets such as ((a)). 
Here's a minimal working example reproducing the double brackets:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,pra,amsmath,amssymb,floatfix,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,epsfig}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
Here's a block of code

\begin{figure}
\centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.41\linewidth}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:subfigure}
     \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Figure caption}
\label{fig:fullFigure}
\end{figure}

I want to reference Fig.~\ref{fig:fullFigure} and in particular Fig.~\ref{fig:subfigure}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, subcaption loads the `parens` label format. As a result, you have double parentheses in subcaptions. You can add `labelformat=simple` to specify the `simple` label format and get the desired output. In your case:

```
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just have use  `\cref` or `\Cref` from the `cleveref` package, according to whether you want  or not an capital *F*. Note this package has to be loaded *after* `hyperref`.

Also, note that you don't have to use parentheses in redefining the subfigure labels: the `subcaption` package already  adds them (unless you want a double pair of parentheses…).

You don't have to load `epsfig`: it is a wrapper to a compatibility mode for old documents. Internally, it is `graphics` which does the job.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,pra,amsmath,amssymb,floatfix,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Here's a block of code

\begin{figure}
\centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.41\linewidth}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:subfigure}
     \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Figure caption}
\label{fig:fullFigure}
\end{figure}

I want to reference \Cref{fig:fullFigure} and in particular \cref{fig:subfigure}.

\end{document}
```

[image]