How to hyperref the subfigures (with tikzpicture)?
How to hyperref the subfigures (with tikzpicture)?
This is my MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
 
\begin{document}

I need to hyperref both the general figure, \cref{fig1}, and the subfigures, i.e. 
 \cref{fig1a}, \cref{fig1b}, and \cref{fig1c}.

\begin{figure}
    \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (4,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=10cm] {example-image-a}}; 
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (12.7cm,-1.2cm) {a};
        \label{fig1a}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (2,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (6.2cm,-0.5cm) {b};
        \label{fig1b}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (2,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-c}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (6.2cm,-0.5cm) {c};
        \label{fig1c}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

...which results in:

My desired output is the following:


Unrelated, but the lower images are misaligned due to the missing % after \end{tikzpicture}

You need something inside your TikZpicture that's labelable. Just a, b and c won't work. See section 7.3 in subcaption package's manual.

Thanks a lot to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and to @Qrrbrbirlbel for your suggestions!
By following the @Qrrbrbirlbel indications I got this solution:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

% Use a mix of the following two solutions to remove the double brackets around the subfigures's references:
% (1) Double bracket in subfigures using subcaption package
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520307/239619
% (2) Adding parentheses around subfig references
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16292/239619
\usepackage[subrefformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}


 
\begin{document}

Now, I can hyperref both the general figure, \cref{fig1}, and the three subfigures, i.e. 
 \cref{fig1a}, \cref{fig1b}, and \cref{fig1c}. Also, I can make a call to multiple referenced subfigures, i.e. to \cref{fig1a,fig1b}, or to \cref{fig1a,fig1b,fig1c}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subcaptiongroup}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (4,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=10cm] {example-image-a}}; 
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (12.7cm,-1.2cm) {a};
        \phantomcaption\label{fig1a}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (2,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (6.2cm,-0.5cm) {b};
        \phantomcaption\label{fig1b}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (2,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-c}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (6.2cm,-0.5cm) {c};
        \phantomcaption\label{fig1c}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{subcaptiongroup}
    \captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
    \caption{Three subfigures: \subref{fig1a}, \subref{fig1b}, and \subref{fig1c}.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

which gives me the following result:

